# Difference between Data source and Output block in terraform

Tags: terraform, cloud

I am not able to figure out what's the difference between data source block and output block in terms of functionality because both are used for getting information about that resource from the console like id, public_ip etc. Can anyone please help me in understanding this because I could'nt find out a suitable resource for this

I have tried to search online for this difference but couldnt find the actual answer.

Comment: `data` is for API resources you are not actively managing in the current Terraform configs, but still require information about.

Answer (score 1):

`data` essentially represents a dependency on an object that isn't managed by the current Terraform configuration but the current Terraform configuration still needs to make use of it. *Mechanically* that typically means making a Get or Read request to a specific API endpoint and then exporting the data from that API response in the resulting attributes.

`output` represents is one of the two ways that data can flow from one module into another. `variable` blocks represent data moving from the parent module into the child module, and `output` blocks represent data moving from the child module out to the parent.

There is no strong relationship between these two concepts but one way they sometimes connect is if you use [the `tfe_outputs` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tfe/latest/docs/data-sources/outputs) belonging to the `hashicorp/tfe` provider, or if you use [the `terraform_remote_state` data source](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/remote-state-data) from the `terraform.io/builtin/terraform` provider. Both of those data sources treat the output values from the root module of some other Terraform configuration as the external object to fetch, and so you can use these as one way to use the results from one configuration as part of another configuration, as long as the second configuration will be run in a context that has access to the state of the first.